# Im getting the following error and i dont know what it means: Error 1 error LNK2019

Tags: c++

ive haveing some trouble. the program worked then when i split it up into each function i got these errors:

Error  1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl calcAVE(int * const,int)" (?calcAVE@@YAHQAHH@Z) referenced in function _main c:\Users\Joshua\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleApplication10\ConsoleApplication10\Source.obj  ConsoleApplication10

please help, thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void getUserInput(int [], int&);
int calcAVE(int [], int);
void outPute(int [], int, int);

int main()
{
    int theAverage = 0;
    int ct = 0;
    const int MAX_SIZE = 100;

    int theArray[MAX_SIZE];

    getUserInput(theArray, ct);
    theAverage = calcAVE(theArray, ct);
    outPute(theArray, ct, theAverage);
    return 0;
}

void getUserInput(int theArray[], int& ct)
{

    int quit = 0;
    int theNums = 0;
    int i = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        cout << "please enter numbers, enter 0 to quit \n";
        cin >> theNums;enter code here

        if (theNums == quit)
        {
            break;
        }

        theArray[ct] = theNums;

        ct++;
    }
}
int calcAve(int theArray[], int ct)
{
    int i = 0;
    int total = 0;
    int average = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < ct; i++)
    {
        total += theArray[i];

        average = total / ct;
    }
    return average;
}
void Output(int theArray [], int ct, int average)
{
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < ct; i++)
    {
        if (theArray[i] > average)
        {
            cout << theArray[i] << ", ";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Typo: `outPute` vs. `Output`

Answer (score 1):

Your function prototype:

```
int calcAVE(int [], int);
```

Your function:

```
int calcAve(int theArray[], int ct)
```

C++ is case sensitive. Therefore, `calcAVE is not the same as calcAve`. You have the same problem with your Output function.

Comment: Thanks, i didn't know what the error was. You guys have been a big help